# Cant remove a key attribute in json while parsing from xml

Tags: node.js, json

```
[{"features":[{"$":{"name":"Default test","durationms":"73546"}}]}]
```

Getting an output like this while converting an xml to json.

Want an output without $ like this:

```
[{"features":[{"name":"Default test","durationms":"73546"}]}]
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance!

And i used 'xml2js'.

Comment: Please share more details, like a sample input document triggering that problem and the code you are using

Comment: You can use `ignoreAttrs` option of xml2js

Answer (score 1):

You can use array `map` method in order to format the data in the expected format

```js
let data = [{"features":[{"$":{"name":"Default test","durationms":"73546"}}]}]

//You can loop through the array
let result = data.map(d => ({
  ...d,
  //Loop through features array and return only the value of "$"
  features: d.features.map(f => f.$)
}))

console.log(result)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Nithish...   but it is showing that data.map is not a function.  i think 'xml2js' is used . Can you provide another solution

Comment: Probably `data` is not defined or not assigned or might not be an array. Please verify once.

Comment: const xml2js = require('xml2js');

Comment: and my output is : [{"features":[{"$":{"name":"Default test","durationms":"73546"}}]}]
 which is assigned to data now.

Comment: If you have the required array in `xml2js` then you can replace `data` with `xml2js` in the above solution.

Comment: thank  u .. @Nithish